# Testing if given linear space of symmetric matrices contains matrix with given eigenspectrum?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, numerical-methods, symmetric-matrices

Imagine we have a linear or affine space of real symmetric $n\times n$ matrices:
$$\mathcal{A}=\{A_0+c_1 A_1+\ldots+c_m A_m: c\in \mathbb{R}^m\}$$
The question is **how to efficiently test if it contains matrix of given eigenspectrum?** Equivalently: **of given characteristic polynomial?**

Trying to expand characteristic polynomial, we get exponential number of terms - the question is if we can test it in polynomial time in $n, m$ e.g. with some numerical procedure?

Examples of eigenspectrum for 1D linear space of $4\times 4$ matrices:
[image]

My motivation is that such test is one of two missing links ([second](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547251/analog-of-vandermonde-determinant-for-fitting-a-quadratic-form)) for testing graph isomorphism in polynomial time: looking at eigenspaces of adjacency matrix, we can transform the problem into question if two sets of points differ only by rotation - e.g. 16 points in 6D forming very regular polyhedron. I wanted to describe this set as $\{x:x^T A x=1\textrm{ for all } A\in\mathcal{A}\}$ intersection of ellipsoids. Having such description for both sets, we could test if they differ by rotation using characteristic polynomial - leading to the test from this question.

---

**Update:** [Here is a useful estimation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4224/eigenvalues-of-matrix-sums) (but no source?), which should allow for a numerical procedure (e.g. some interleaving steps of [QR algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) and mixing of matrices):

> A simple estimate which is often useful is that, if $A$ and $B$ are
>   Hermitian matrices with eigenvalues $a_1 > a_2 > \ldots > a_n$ and 
>   $b_1 > b_2 > \ldots > b_n$ and the eigenvalues of the sum are $c_1 > c_2 > \ldots > c_n$, then
>   $$ c_{i+j-1} \le a_i + b_j \quad\text{and}\quad c_{n-i-j} \ge a_{n-i} + b_{n-j}. $$