# If $0\leq A\leq B$ and $C\geq0$ then does $0\leq AC\leq BC$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space with inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. We say $A\geq 0$ if $\langle Ax,x\rangle\geq0$ for all $x\in H$. If $0\leq A\leq B$ and $C\geq0$ then does $0\leq AC\leq BC$?

Comment: Just to double check, $B \geq A$ means $B - A \geq 0$, right?

Comment: As pointed out by a comment to your other question, it doesn't make sense to ask whether $AC\ge0$, as $AC$ is in general not self-adjoint.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the comment of user1551, lack of self-adjointness can be fixed as follows:

> Let bounded linear operators $A,B,C$ on $H$ be given. If $0\leq A\leq B$ and $C\geq 0$, then
> $$
> 0\leq \sqrt CA\sqrt C\leq\sqrt CB\sqrt C
> $$
> where $\sqrt C$ is the [unique square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4417721) of $C$.

Because $\sqrt C\geq 0$ it in particular is self-adjoint meaning
$$
\langle x,\sqrt CA\sqrt Cx\rangle=\langle(\sqrt Cx),A(\sqrt Cx)\rangle\geq 0
$$
for all $x\in H$ because $A\geq 0$. Analogously one sees $\sqrt C(B-A)\sqrt C\geq 0$.